# Finding the reaction forces of a bridge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

> There is a bridge supported at both ends. The reaction forces at the ends are currently the same. A vehicle comes on to the bridge and stops at 50 m from one of the ends. What are the reaction forces from the two supports? Bridge is 5000 kg, vehicle is 1000 kg and the bridge's full length is 200 m.

I know the answers because my physics teacher did it in class. But here's the thing. The reaction force from the vehicle was ignored because it's taken as a weight on the bridge.

Can someone explain this to me a little bit more and how this works?

Comment: There is most certainly a reaction force exerted by the vehicle on the bridge.

Comment: Voting to reopen. Clearly a conceptual question not a "do my homework for me" question.

Comment: Please give us the calculation of your teacher and explain where you miss the reaction force of the vehicle. it seems hidden in the calculation since it exists.

Answer (score 0):

The bridge exerts a force on the vehicle that is equal and opposite to the vehicle's weight. Due to Newton's 3rd Law the vehicle in turn exerts a reaction force on the bridge that is equal and opposite to force exerted by the bridge on the vehicle. So the vehicle exerts a force on the bridge that is equal to the vehicle's weight.

So the reaction force exerted by the vehicle on the bridge *is the same* as the vehicle's weight. You do not need to include both the reaction force exerted by the vehicle on the bridge *and* the vehicle's weight - that would be double counting.

So the total downwards force on the bridge is equal to the bridge's weight plus the vehicle's weight, which gives a total force of $6000$ N. But we know that the net force on the bridge must be zero. So the upwards force on the bridge - which is the sum of the forces at the bridge supports - must also be $6000$ N. And the vehicle is three times as far from one support as it is from the other ($50$ m from one and $150$ m from the other). So the force exerted on the bridge by the support that is closer to the vehicle is three times as large as the force exerted on the bridge by the support that is further from the vehicle.